# Form Validation with Jquery with if statements

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, forms

I'm about to release my personal website but stucked with contact form validation. I want visitors to properly enter every field. While I'm doing this, I can go for both sides (either javascript or php validation). But the page is static HTML, only requests for mail.php for sending it. (Using PHPMAILER).

What I want is basically users to get notified in each field, then if they enter everything properly, I want them to submit the form and show the success message, without redirecting them. So here is my code and I appreciate for your help.

```
                        <form name="form1" id="contact-form" method="post" role="form">
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-pb-sm animate-box">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="name" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="email" required="required" pattern="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <textarea class="form-control" required="required" name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="7" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary" formaction="mail.php" onsubmit="return ValidateLoginForm();">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1 form-align" id="form_response"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div id="footer">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                            <p>
                                Copyright © 2020 Umut Pirinci.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>



    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery Easing -->
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <!-- animateAnything -->
    <script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/409445/animateAnything.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Waypoints -->
    <script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Owl Carousel -->
    <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Magnific Popup -->
    <script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/magnific-popup-options.js"></script>

    <!-- Main JS (Do not remove) -->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
            $('a[href*=\\#]:not([href=\\#])').on('click', function() {
                    var target = $(this.hash);
                    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.substr(1) +']');
                    if (target.length) {
                            $('html,body').animate({
                                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                            }, 1000);
                            return false;
                    }
            });
    });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
                $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
                    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
                        var url = "mail.php";

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: url,
                            data: $(this).serialize(),
                            success: function (data) {
                                var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                                var messageText = data.message;
                                var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                                if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                                    $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                                    $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        return false;

                    }
                })
            });
    </script>
    <script>
    function ValidateLoginForm() {
        var name = document.form1.name;
        var message = document.form1.message;
        var email = document.form1.email;

        if (name.value == "") {
            alert("Your name wasn't recognised.");
            name.focus();
            return false;
        }

        if (message.value == "") {
            alert("Please enter your message.");
            message.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (email.value == "") {
            alert("Please enter your email address.");
            email.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    </script>
    <script>
            function form_sub() {
                $('#form_response').html('Your form has been successfully sent!').fadeIn(1500).delay(5000).fadeOut(1500);
            }
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things you need to do:

1- input with type submit you need to remove the onsubmit attribute as this attribute must be added on FORM tag only.
2- try to combine submission functions with only one.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="form1" id="contact-form" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-pb-sm animate-box">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="name" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" required="required" pattern="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" required="required" name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="7" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary" formaction="mail.php">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1 form-align" id="form_response"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        ValidateLoginForm();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    })
    function ValidateLoginForm() {
        var name = document.form1.name;
        var message = document.form1.message;
        var email = document.form1.email;

        if (name.value == "") {
            alert("Your name wasn't recognised.");
            name.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (message.value == "") {
            alert("Please enter your message.");
            message.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (email.value == "") {
            alert("Please enter your email address.");
            email.focus();
            return false;
        } else {
            var url = "mail.php";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;
                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Moayad. I did exactly what you said and code looks beautiful but this time it does not validate somehow. Eventhough I added onsubmit to <form> tags. Do you have any idea what could be the reason for that?

Comment: Hi, please remove the on submit attribute from the form and check your console if there are any javascript errors. as I have just tried the code and it works perfectly **please check my answer edit**

Comment: Hi Moayad, I just tried the code and it seems working,however, I don't receive email this time. The error I get from the console is usual map issue. `code` DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://*******/****/js/jquery.min.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Comment: Hi, This might be because in my example I added newer version of jQuery, try using the version you were using before and tell if this works or not. either ways the error telling you to include the .map file also, you can find it here:
**https://github.com/jquery/codeorigin.jquery.com/blob/master/cdn/jquery-3.2.1.min.map**

Comment: Hi Moayad, I just found that it is totally caused by version of Jquery. So your solution now works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help!